# Express some equations as polynomial equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given 
$$\begin{align*}
x&=(2+\cos(2s))\cos(3s)\\
y&=(2+\cos(2s))\sin(3s)\\
z&=\sin(2s),\end{align*}$$
I was wondering how to express these equations as polynomial equations in $x$, $y$, $z$, $a=\cos(s)$, $b=\sin(s)$.

Thanks!

Edit: I expect that the polynomial equations can give the same surface in $\mathbb R^3.$

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align*}
x^2&=(2+\cos(2s)^2\cos(3s)^2\\
y^2&=(2+\cos(2s)^2\sin(3s)^2\\

x^2+y^2&=(2+\cos(2s))^2(\cos(3s)^2+sin(3s)^2)=(2+\cos(2s))^2\\

x^2+y^2&=(2+\cos(2s))^2=4+4\cos(2s)+\cos(2s)^2=4+4\cos(2s)+(1-\sin(2s)^2)\\

x^2+y^2&=5+4\cos(2s)-z^2\\

x^2+y^2+z^2&=5+4(\cos(s)^2-\sin(s)^2)\\

x^2+y^2+z^2&=5+4a^2-4b^2\\







,\end{align*}$$

$$x^2+y^2+z^2-4a^2+4b^2-5=0$$

Comment: Thanks. But can you ensure that they give the _same_ curve? It seems that $3s$ is not "fully" used. If given $\cos(4s)$ instead of $\cos(3s)$, then your result will remain the same...

Comment: For example, if given $\{x=(2+\cos(t))\cos(u),y=(2+\cos(t))\sin(u),z=\sin(t)\}$, let $a=\cos(t),b=\sin(t), c=\cos(u), d=\sin(u),$ rewrite the equations as polynomial equations in $a,b,c,d,x,y,z.$ Then how to write it?

Comment: Sorry, not curve, it should have been a surface in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: @Emily: That would just give $x=(2+a)c$, $y=(2+a)d$, $z=b$? Those are certainly polynomial equations. What is it that you're _really_ trying to do? Perhaps "rewrite as polynomial equations in such-and-such" does not succeed in communicating to us what your requirements are.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the [double- and triple-angle formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-.2C_triple-.2C_and_half-angle_formulae).

Comment: Thanks, see my question below the other answer please.

Comment: I don't understand that question.

Comment: I just added an example.

Comment: See my new post [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121952/did-i-write-the-right-expressions). Thanks!