# Did I write the right "expressions"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, trigonometry, computational-geometry

> $9$. Consider the parametric curve $K\subset R^3$ given by
>   $$x = (2 + \cos(2s)) \cos(3s)$$
>   $$y = (2 + \cos(2s)) \sin(3s)$$
>   $$z = \sin(2s)$$
>   a) Express the equations of *K* as polynomial equations in $x,\ y,\ z,\ a = \cos(s),\ b = \sin(s)$.
>   **Hint**: Trig identities.
>
> b) By computing a Groebner basis for the ideal generated by the equations from part $a$ and $a^2 + b^2 - 1$ as in Exercise 8, show that *K* is (a subset of) an afﬁne algebraic curve. Find implicit equations for a curve containing *K*.
>
> c) Show that the equation of the surface from Exercise 8 is contained in the ideal generated
>   by the equations from part b. What does this result mean geometrically? (You can actually reach the same conclusion by comparing the parametrizations of *T* and *K*, without
>   calculations.)

I try to solve this problem, on page 102 of Cox's "Ideal, varieties and algorithms: an introduction to computational algebraic geometry and commutative algebra".

On the first question, I get
$$x=(2+2\cos^2s-1)(4\cos^3s-3\cos s)=(1+2a^2)(4a^3-3a),$$
$$y=(1+2a^2)(3\sin s-4\sin^3 s)=(1+2a^2)(3b-4b^3),$$
$$z=2ab.$$

I was wondering whether they are *right*, since the Groebner basis given by them is extremely bad, 
[image: Grobner basis]

Any comments? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth: you could try easing things a bit for your Gröbner basis computations by using the Weierstrass substitutions

$$\begin{align*}\cos\,s&=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}\\\sin\,s&=\frac{2u}{1+u^2}\end{align*}$$

after of course using multiple angle identities to expand out the trigonometric functions. Since it seems you're using *Mathematica*, here's how I'd do it if I were in your shoes:

```
GroebnerBasis[TrigExpand[
    Thread[{x, y, z} == {(2 + Cos[2 s]) Cos[3 s],
            (2 + Cos[2 s]) Sin[3 s], Sin[2 s]}]] /. 
   Thread[{Cos[s], Sin[s]} -> {(1 - u^2)/(1 + u^2), (2 u)/(
      1 + u^2)}], {x, y, z}, u] // FullSimplify
```

On the other hand, it does seem that Cox/Little/O'Shea is asking you to do it the long way, so here's the "painful" route:

```
GroebnerBasis[Append[TrigExpand[
     Thread[{x, y, z} ==
       {(2 + Cos[2 s]) Cos[3 s], (2 + Cos[2 s]) Sin[3 s], 
        Sin[2 s]}]] /. Thread[{Cos[s], Sin[s]} -> {a, b}], 
   a^2 + b^2 == 1], {x, y, z}, {a, b}] // FullSimplify
```

It's not too hard to do a sanity check of the results of `GroebnerBasis[]`. Here's one way (to be done after executing the previous snippet):

```
% /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> {(2 + Cos[2 s]) Cos[3 s],
     (2 + Cos[2 s]) Sin[3 s], Sin[2 s]}] // Simplify
```

If everything went well, you should be getting a list containing a bunch of zeroes.

As I am writing this, I don't have *Mathematica* installed on the computer I'm using. It can happen that one of the the two options I gave might give a longer list of ideals, but it's guaranteed that one would be a subset of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your expressions are correct. 
For further practices, you can try:

$$\begin{align*}
\cos(ax)&=\frac{e^{iax}+e^{-iax}}{2}\\
\sin(ax)&=\frac{e^{iax}-e^{-iax}}{2i}
\end{align*}$$